Is there a way to play midi sound without having another application such as garageband opened?
I have the code below where I'm trying to play a note in mac from a python application. Unfortunately I have noticed that the only way that the sound is audible is when garageband is opened.
Is there a way to play midi sound without having another application such as garageband opened?
I know this is possible in java.
import time
import rtmidi as rtmidi

def open_midi():
    
        midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
        available_ports = midiout.get_ports()
    
    
        if available_ports:
            print("Available ports")
            midiout.open_port(0)
        else:
            print("Openning virtual ports")
            midiout.open_virtual_port("My virtual output")
        return midiout
    def play(note):
        with open_midi() as midiout:
            while True:
                note_on = [0x90, note, 112] # channel 1, middle C, velocity 112
                note_off = [0x80, note, 0]
                midiout.send_message(note_on)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                midiout.send_message(note_off)
                time.sleep(0.1)
    
        del midiout
    play(60)


You do not need garageband . Windows media player can play midi files. https://www.guidingtech.com/what-are-midi-files-and-how-to-open-them-in-windows-11/

Most Macs have Logic already installed and it will be able to play some midi.

I'm on a mac by the way; does that still apply?

It's just that I don't want to package software that requires the existence of another app; is there a way to do this?

I would research options for automating midi setup via install shield or some other advanced packager.

@BartMcEndree Please note the OP uses a Mac, not Windows. He won't have (or want) Windows Media Player nor will anything that uses InstallShield be of the slightest use or interest.

You should understand the difference between MIDI and Audio. These things are completely different.
MIDI is not about producing sound. It just provides commands for another part of your musical setup - synth, DAW, sampler and so on. So you just say "Well, now I want to start a note". But how that note will be started depends on other software that produces sound (audio) from MIDI commands.
So you cannot get sound from MIDI with just MIDI. It's required to use software for producing sound.
